# Centroid with side ratios

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $G$ denote the centroid of triangle $ABC$. Let $M$ and $N$ be points on sides $AB$ and $AC$, respectively, so that $M$, $G$, and $N$ are collinear, and $ AM/MB = 5/2 $. Find $AN/NC$.

I tried to approach this problem with vectors. But haven't been able to get anything reasonable. Any ides/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can transform any triangle $ABC$ into a triangle of convenient shape and size by doing linear transformations. Let's choose an isosceles triangle with base and height both $1$. We do a two-dimensional expansion/contraction to make $AB=1$, then a shear transformation along line $AB$ to make it isosceles with $AC=BC$, followed by a one-dimensional expansion/contraction perpendicular to line $AB$ to make the height $1$. Those three transformations do not change any of the data or the unknown, so you can assume without loss of generality that $AB=1$ and the height of triangle $ABC$ perpendicular to $AB$ is also $1$.

[image]

We can then place triangle $ABC$ on a Cartesian plane. If we place $A$ at the origin and $B$ at $(1,0)$ then $C$ is at $(1/2,1)$, and centroid $G$ is at $(1/2, 1/3)$. Point $M$ is at $(5/7,0)$.

Then find the equations for the lines through $A$ and $C$ (very easy) and through $G$ and $M$ (less easy but not hard), and solve the simultaneous equations to find the location of point $N$.

The desired ratio will then be easy to find from the $y$-coordinates of $A$, $N$, and $C$. I get the ratio $\frac{5/8}{3/8}=\frac 53$.

(A previous version of this answer made the triangle $ABC$ equilateral, but the current version makes all the relevant points have rational coordinates.)